# why does object.variable work in the main class and in other classes?

Tags: processing

I am currently building Space Invaders in Processing and I do not absolutely understand why this happens, it is hard to explain, so here is all the code that goes with the game:
SpaceInvaders.pde:

```java
/* Jordan Green
April 11th, 2018
This is the main class for the game
Space Invaders.
This is what sets up the game.
*/
//My objects declared.
Alien aliens;
Player player;
Score score;
PImage img;
//sets up the variables and gives them values.
void setup() {
  aliens = new Alien();
  player = new Player();
  score = new Score();
  size (600, 600);
  img = loadImage("Space Background.jpg");
}

//draws out the program.
void draw() {
  background(0);
  image(img, 0, 0, height, width);
  player.show();
  player.move();
  player.playerLives();
  player.alienDie();
  aliens.show();
  aliens.move();
  score.show();
  if (player.playerLife == 0) {

  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    player.shoot();
  }
}
```

My question is why does an object.variable work on Processing? It's something I do not understand.

Jordan

Comment: In the future please post a [mcve] instead of your full project.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it work?

This is a fundamental feature of objects in Java, which Processing is built on top of. If you have a class that contains variables or functions, you can reference those variables or functions using the `.` dot operator.

Here's an example:

```
class MyClass{
  int x = 42;

  void sayHello(){
    println("hello");
  }
}

MyClass myInstanceOfMyClass = new MyClass();
println(myInstanceOfMyClass.x);
myInstanceOfMyClass.sayHello();
```

In Java you can mark variables and functions as `private` to restrict access, but this is less common in Processing.

You can read more about classes in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/class.html) or in [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes).